# Unit testing aurelia view

Tags: jasmine, aurelia, jasmine-jquery

I'm new to Aurelia and was wondering if there was a way to unit test the Aurelia views with it's custom bindings? I tried to load the Aurelia html view file into an html fixture using jasmine-jquery, but for some reason I could never get any of the html DOM elements using their id.

The functionality I am trying to unit test is when I mouseover an icon, it should increase the size of the icon and change it's background color.

View

```
<template>
<div>
    <span repeat.for="[automobile] of automobilesArray">
        <object id.bind="automobile.Id" type="image/svg+xml" style='background-color: white;' data.bind="'./images/' + automobile.Id +'.svg'" class="auto-icon img-circle" width="50" mouseover.delegate="mover($event)" mouseout.delegate="mout($event)">
        </object>
    </span>
</div>
```

View Model

```
    mover(event: Event) {
    document.getElementById(event.srcElement.id).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    document.getElementById(event.srcElement.id).width = "60px";
}
mout(event: Event) {
    document.getElementById(event.srcElement.id).style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById(event.srcElement.id).width = "60px";        
}
```

I'd like to write something like this in my test file to test this. What am I doing wrong?

Test file

```
    it("vehicle icons should grow in size on mouseover",  => () {
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/';
    loadFixtures('view.html');

    expect($('#automobile.Id')).toHaveCss({ width: "50px" });

    $('#automobile.Id').mouseover();

    expect($('#automobile.Id')).toHaveCss({ width: "60px" });
});
```

Comment: There are some test examples in the skeleton project. Are you using them?

Comment: I did take a look at the examples in the skeleton project, but it didn't seem to have what I was looking to do. Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an end to end test using something like protractor.  Jasmine unit tests are not meant to actually have the app fully load and prepare everything like a full end to end test.  To achieve this please take a look at the end to end tests in the skeleton-navigation applications.

Comment: Thanks, I'll create an e2e test for it.